# How to pass objects to functions in javascript between different click events?

Tags: javascript

Why is this code indicating that my object's properties are undefined?

```
document.getElementById("mkObj").addEventListener('click', () => {

        var globalDragon = mkObj(document.getElementById("cn").value, parseInt(document.getElementById("ch").value), document.getElementById("cl").value);

        document.getElementById("hit").addEventListener('click', (globalDragon) => {

            hit(globalDragon, 25);

            printObjDetails(globalDragon);

        });

        document.getElementById("details").addEventListener('click', (globalDragon) => {

            let dragon_here = globalDragon;


            printObjDetails(dragon_here);

        });

    });
```

Why can't I just make the Dragon object by clicking the mkObj button and then click the hit button or details button and have it show the object's state? Why is it showing that globalDragon.name is undefined?

I had the code looking like this before and it did not work either so I just make everything be within the mkObj click scope, thinking that that would solve the issue but it didn't:

```
document.getElementById("mkObj").addEventListener('click', ()=>{

    var globalDragon = mkObj( document.getElementById("cn").value, parseInt( document.getElementById("ch").value), document.getElementById("cl").value );

     });
    document.getElementById("hit").addEventListener('click', (globalDragon)=>{

    hit(globalDragon, 25);

    printObjDetails(globalDragon);

     });

    document.getElementById("details").addEventListener('click', (globalDragon)=>{

    let dragon_here = globalDragon;


    printObjDetails(dragon_here);
    
     });
```

Comment: Adding event listeners *inside* other event listeners is almost always questionable if not a mistake. The `.addEventListener()` call does not remove already-added listeners, so when a "click" happens *all* added listeners will run.

Comment: you're defining a `var` variable in the scope of that click listener - `globalDragon` doesn't exist outside of that function and will be `undefined` in your other click listeners

Comment: @Kinglish It's worse than that. `globalDragon` is redefined as a parameter. So, within the listener, `globalDragon` is an event object.

Comment: As @GarrGodfrey points out you need to go back to the documentation of `addEventListener`. You can't arbitrarily change the callback arguments to something else. Lots of issues to sort out in this code

Comment: so there is no way to click a button and bring a global object into existence and then do whatever you want to it via other event handlers? e.g. pass it to functions, print it, etc.

Comment: you see this type of set up works with console programs but apparently not with GUIs... am I understanding that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you actually want is

```
// declare the variable in the top scope,
// so that all three click handlers can access it
var globalDragon;

document.getElementById("mkObj").addEventListener('click', () => {
    // write a new object into the global variable
    globalDragon = mkObj(
        document.getElementById("cn").value,
        parseInt( document.getElementById("ch").value),
        document.getElementById("cl").value
    );
});

document.getElementById("details").addEventListener('click', () => {
    // read from the global variable
    printObjDetails(globalDragon);
});

document.getElementById("hit").addEventListener('click', () => {
    // modify the object
    hit(globalDragon, 25);
    printObjDetails(globalDragon);
});
```

Notice how I removed the parameters of the functions that were also named `globalDragon`. The event handlers get passed an event object as their arguments.